# .NET MAUI Full scale background image (overlay elements)

Tags: xaml, background, overlay, maui

Since .NET MAUI is the successor of Xamarin, i am trying to port a Xamarin layout to the new Maui version. The `RelativeLayout` is removed from Maui. I used the `RelativeLayout` to position a GUI on top of an image. This image is a full screen background image, stretched in the length, keeping its ratio.

I could create the same layout, but with an full screen image in the background that is 100% height and keeps its ratio. How would I do this in .NET Maui? Its not realy about how to make an image stretch but put layout elements (Like entry, label, etc) on top of an image.

Comment: Including your Xamarin code and a screenshot will for sure help others to understand your question

Comment: Use [Absolute Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout). This works the same as it did in X Forms. Math a bit different than `RelativeLayout`, but should not be hard to adapt. An Alternative is `Grid`; items in same row and column are on top of each other. And ColumnSpan/RowSpan are useful to have one item cover multiple cells.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Example using Grid:

```cs
<!-- single cell grid filling its parent. -->
<Grid>
  <!-- both children default to cell (0,0). Overlaid. -->
  <Image Aspect="AspectFit" ... />
  <!-- nested grid. OR StackLayout, etc. -->
  <Grid ... >
    <!-- GUI content here. -->
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can work with this. I had no clue that cells could be overlaid!

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I did this already, but there are what appears to be automatic safe insets in MAUI for nav and toolbar on iOS. Any idea how to remove the top and bottom "padding"? I already zeroed the padding on my custom component. Thanks.

Comment: @jmichas - Create a question showing your code, with an image, that you annotate to show exactly what padding you seek to remove. My first guess is that it is related to Maui's implementation of AppShell (which I don't use; I prefer having total control over layout and navigation, so I do `MainPage = new NavigationPage()`, and write my own code for custom toolbar and nav.)

Comment: Sadly I've noticed in one of the latest MAUI version (.NET7 not sure if its only there but that's the version i am using) This does not work for me on android. My iOS looks nice but many Android views are completely broken. Not all views, sometimes it does work. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Is it just a "safe area" (padding) issue, or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone reading this, the above answer works fines, however there is currently an issue (maybe a feature?) in MAUI where a safe area padding is added automatically to the the root view of a page.

Disabeling the safe area via code does not fix the issue, it will only remove the margin, not the padding.

In my case, I ended up writing a markup extention for ios

In the shared code I created

```cs
    public partial class RemoveTopBottomSafeArea : IMarkupExtension<Thickness>
    {
        public Thickness Thickness { get; set; } = new Thickness();

        public Thickness ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            AdjustThickness();

            return Thickness;
        }

        object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return (this as IMarkupExtension<Thickness>).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        }

        partial void AdjustThickness();
    }
```

The in the iOS platform folder I created an extention method to get the key window

```cs
public static UIKit.UIWindow GetKeyWindow(this UIApplication uiApplication)
{
    if (OperatingSystem.IsIOSVersionAtLeast(13))
    {
        using var scenes = uiApplication.ConnectedScenes;
        var windowScene = scenes.ToArray<UIKit.UIWindowScene>().FirstOrDefault();
        return windowScene?.Windows.FirstOrDefault();
    }
// use the windows property (up to 13.0)
    return uiApplication.KeyWindow;
}
```

In iOS platform folder I then created the implementation to adjust the Thickness

```cs
public partial class RemoveTopBottomSafeArea 
{
    partial void AdjustThickness() 
    {
        var window = UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication.GetKeyWindow();
        var safeAreaInsets = window.SafeAreaInsets;

        Thickness = new Thickness(Thickness.Left, Thickness.Top - safeAreaInsets.Top, Thickness.Right, Thickness.Bottom - safeAreaInsets.Bottom);
    }
}
```

And then finally on the root view I applied it like so

```xml
<Grid Padding="{ext:RemoveTopBottomSafeArea}">
        <Image
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Source="yourimage.jpg"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

There's probably a much neater way to do it, but it works.

Comment: Hi @Richard, can you please tell in detail where to add method GetKeyWindow in iOS?

Comment: Hi @AkhilGite 

You'll have to add it somewhere in the plaform specific folder. See below for  reference

Project\Platforms\iOS\Extentions\UIApplicationExtentions.cs