# Maui XAML Spinner displaces fields in my form when it becomes visible

Tags: android, xaml, .net-maui

I'm working on a Maui app (non-blazer) and only targeting Android.

I have an ActivityIndicator (Spinner) that I activate and deactivate using binding.

When the Spinner becomes visible it shifts all fields below down to make room for the spinner.

I would think there is a way to make the spinner overlay all fields instead -- like an absolute location in html; but, I've not figured a way to do that.

Here's some of my XAML

```
<ActivityIndicator 
    x:Name="theSpinner"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" 
    IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" />
```

How can I make the spinner appear on top of all other fields?

Comment: The symptom involves how the spinner interacts with layout of other items. Therefore, add to question the declaration of enclosing layout (presumably Grid), as well as one of the items that gets overlaid - which should be a child of the same Grid. You can overlay grid children by giving them same row and column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET MAUI Full scale background image (overlay elements)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73671695/net-maui-full-scale-background-image-overlay-elements)

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I suspected all the other controls on the page would disappear when the spinner was made visible but it was dead center and showed on-top-of everything behind it.  Thank you!!