# MAUI equivalent to CSS background-repeat: repeat;

Tags: background, maui

I've followed existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73671695/net-maui-full-scale-background-image-overlay-elements) on how to add image as a background for your MAUI app. This works fine, but I would like to have image repeated rather than filled. Equivalent with CSS would be [background-repeat: repeat;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat)

Anyone knows a way to achieve this?

I currently have the following code from answer I've mentioned before

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="CartographersMapGenerator.View.Testing"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Title="Testing">
    <Grid>
        <Image Aspect="AspectFit" Source="dotnet_bot.png" />
        <Grid>
            <Label>
                All page content goes here
            </Label>
        </Grid>
       
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Which gives the following result:

[image: Code result]

Comment: There isn't any such Maui option. For each of the platforms you target, you'd have to research how to make a repeating image. Then write a custom handler that does that. Then use that handler to render a subclass of Image, that you use in your xaml instead of `<Image>`.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no repeat option for the The  in maui. For more information about [Images in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows).

Second, you can refer to the [SkiaSharp bitmap tiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/effects/shaders/bitmap-tiling), it provides the method to tile bitmaps.