In Maui, how can I set Grid\Border\Frame background as tiled, given a sample tile for it to fill with?
I am developing a Maui game and I want to set each game level background (Grid but could also be Border\Frame) according to its level type. I want to do so using a sample tile image that will be duplicated to fill the background.
Is this possible out of the box? Or should I write a custom control for it?
For example i'm looking for something like: (More explanation added)
<Border>
    <Border.Background>
        <Image Source="volcano_tile.png" Mode="Tiled"/>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>

volcano_tile.png:

And the expected result would be to fill the entire border background with multiple tiles:

Thanks!

It's totally unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75280677/3392605

I did not find a standard easy xaml way to do it, so I have implemented a solution using SkiaSharp:
This is my Tester code:
First, I have created a helper class that receives width and height of the wanted target tiled image, and the tileImage itself. Using SKBitmap, it builds and returns the tiled image:
internal class ImageTiler
{
    public static SKBitmap CreateTiledImage(int width, int height, SKBitmap tileImage)
    {
        // Create a new bitmap with the desired dimensions
        var tiledBitmap = new SKBitmap(width, height);
        using (var canvas = new SKCanvas(tiledBitmap))
        {
            // Loop through the width and height of the new image
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y += tileImage.Height)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x += tileImage.Width)
                {
                    // Draw the tile image at the current position
                    canvas.DrawBitmap(tileImage, x, y);
                }
            }
        }
        return tiledBitmap;
    }

    public static SKBitmap LoadImage(string resourcePath)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = $"TilesTester.Resources.Images.{resourcePath}";
        
        //var imageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(resourcePath);
        using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            return SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
        }
    }
}

Than I have loaded my resource png tile image, and used the ImageTiler to build and display it using a SKCanvasView:
// Load the image to be tiled
string imagePath = "volcanotile.png";
SKBitmap tileImage = ImageTiler.LoadImage(imagePath);

// Define the dimensions of the new image
int newWidth = 800;
int newHeight = 600;

// Create the tiled image
SKBitmap tiledImage = ImageTiler.CreateTiledImage(newWidth, newHeight, tileImage);

var canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
canvasView.PaintSurface += (sender, args) =>
{
    var canvas = args.Surface.Canvas;
    canvas.Clear();
    canvas.DrawBitmap(tiledImage, new SKRect(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));
};

// Add the SKImageView as a Content to the page
Content = canvasView;

The result (Modified screenshot after changing to better Tile image and adding dynamic Tile selection):

